# Cloud Function triggered by Pub Sub doesn't publish expected message

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-chat

I have the following google cloud function:

```
def run_msg(event, context):
    
    print(event["data"])
    url = 'google_chat_hook'

    bot_message = {
        'text' : '{}'.format(event["data"])}

    message_headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}

    http_obj = Http()

    response = http_obj.request(
        uri=url,
        method='POST',
        headers=message_headers,
        body=dumps(bot_message),
    )
```

When I'm testing the function directly from the Cloud Function Interface with the following trigger event `{"data": {"message": "test"}}` I have the right message being published in google chat => `{"message": "test"}` but when I'm publishing a message from pub sub manually I have the following kind of stuff being posted on google chat `iB7Im1lc3NhZ2UiOiAibXNnX2Nvb2wifX`

I can't understand what's happening here.

Comment: Data published by pubsub is base64 encoded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply copy paste the sample code in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#sample_code)

```
base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
```

Voilà! It's base64 encoded. Decode it and you will see it!